# Syntek 1160 causing crash of VirtualBox

Tags: ubuntu, usb, virtualbox

I have a Syntek 1160 based USB dongle to capture feed from a traditional PAL camera. I am able to view and record the feed with VLC or ffmpeg on Linux. Unfortunately for the purpose of my project I am forced to use Windows 7. Because of this I have installed VirtualBox and virtualised Ubuntu. After that I have filtered USB, so that Syntek is always seen on the linux side. With such setup `lsusb` command shows USB device and /dev/video0 is present. However the whole VirtualBox application crashes when I am trying to watch the feed with VLC (Media -> Open Capture Device -> Video device name -> /dev/video0). I get a critical error on the Win7 side saying: `Trying to access <number_here>. Memory cannot be read <or_written>`

How can I use Syntek device on virtualised Ubuntu with Win7 host? How should I configure virtualbox? Or maybe it is better to use different vm software?

Comment: Have you used other virtual machine solutions to verify this isn't a problem with just Virtualbox?

Comment: Yes I have. I have tried parallels running on OSX

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Comment: Sure. I have a macbook pro with latest parallels software. I run Ubuntu 14.04 as a virtual system. I have also configured syntek device to always connect to Ubuntu. I am able to watch, record and stream the feed with VLC and ffmpeg. I would like to achieve the same performance with Win7 host

Comment: So you have the same exact problems with a parallel virtual machine running a Ubuntu installation?  Honestly the problem sounds like a VirtualBox issue which is the reason I asked if the problem exists with other virtual machine software ( i.e. Hyper-V, Parrallels, ect. )

Comment: Abou the quality of VirtualBox, please see http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=OTk5Mw and https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/10/6/317

Comment: @Ramhound No. I don't have any problems with parallels solution. I agree, it is problem with vm software. I edited my question to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae, do you have any experience with similar problems? Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: 1. Yes I do. 2. I do not, unfortunately. The only suggestion I can offer is: make a copy of the working version of the VM in ova format, and import it into Windows' VirtualBox. If Parallels cannot do that, use VirtulBox for Mac OSX. Try to see whether this way you circumvent the problem. I once succeeded, but I am not sure it was anything but a stroke of luck.